# Lots of Small Requests over Broadband Connection - Slow Response Times?

Tags: ping, vmware, virtual

I have setup my dual e5-2697 V2 system; using VMWARE WorkStation Pro 12, to run roughly 30 VMs concurrently.

While the machines do a lot of "small requests", ping type requests, nothing more then sending/receiving small kbytes of data; my overall network connection with Comcast (broadband 300mbps) is suffering from ping times.

The overall speed is still good... so downloading a large file still performs as expected, but navigating websites is slow, as if all the little pings the 30 machines create cause an overall slowdown of all the "little requests".

Is there any way to better manage this networking wise?

I've searched for the answer, but can't seem to come up with a solution that actually improves the issue I am having.

Many thanks!

Comment: What DNS are you using?

Comment: 4.4.4.4 and 8.8.8.8

Comment: I think you meant to use `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`, the Google DNS servers. You may be going slow because it needs the incorrect `4.4.4.4` to time out before it can use the correct `8.8.8.8`.

Comment: indeed ron is right. your behaviour points to dns problems. 4.4.4.4 is a private isp dns that once was open to the world

Comment: Wow ok let me check to see if this helps. I think this may be the issue. Will report back. And thank you, because I would have never figured that to be the issue (as I didn't know that was even incorrect). Will post back shortly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your behaviour of slow browsing and fast file transfers is consistent with DNS problems.

As you stated, you are using as DNS servers 4.4.4.4 and 8.8.8.8.

It is a common mistake assuming 4.4.4.4 is a Google DNS Server (or it was in the past, not so sure). It belongs to Level 3 Communications, and it is only open for their customers.

```
$whois 4.4.4.4
....
Level 3 Communications, Inc. LVLT-STATIC-4-4-16 (NET-4-4-0-0-1) 4.4.0.0 - 4.4.255.255
```

I do advise you to correct it to the appropriate [Google DNS servers](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using#important_before_you_start).

> The Google Public DNS IP addresses (IPv4) are as follows:
>
> ```
> 8.8.8.8
> 8.8.4.4
> ```
>
> The Google Public DNS IPv6 addresses are as follows:
>
> ```
> 2001:4860:4860::8888   
> 2001:4860:4860::8844
> ```

For the number of servers you have,  it maybe worth setting up a local DNS server, or at least a local DNS forwarding cache.

Comment: I will have to look into and read up on setting up my own DNS, I know my diskstation can support it. I made the changes to my DNS to the correct settings. I will have to let it be for a bit to see if I notice a huge difference. In my modem settings, the IPv6 DNS settings to not seem to be something I can manually set; perhaps they are set by the IPv4 automatically?   Lastly; would there be a better DNS to use? Based on Geolocation, should I search for something closer, or are there higher speed DNS options out there?

Comment: See Namebench. Take it with a pinch of salt because it tends to favour google servers. I prefer to setup my own. Please see this. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253841/large-zone-file-for-bind9-ad-blocking/253879

Comment: Thank you for the info I will take a look at that thread. I'm sure if its clear I can set it up. Let me see how this goes, with the correct DNS settings; and report back.  Thank you to all for pointing that out! I would have likely used that for all eternity otherwise!